# Automatic <C-g>u to break undo block?

Tags: undo-redo

What possible downsides are there to using `<C-g>u` on a regular basis to break the undo chain in small chunks, e.g. after every line-break or after every sentence? Has someone experiences with this?

Comment: Related reading: Drew Neil’s book Practical Vim has a chapter where he discusses “pausing with your paintbrush off the canvas”—basically, hit escape any time you pause. The habit is worth it.

Comment: I thought of a script or a mapping, like :imap <Space> <Space><CTRL>gu  or so...

Comment: Yes some people do this after entering punctuation or pressing enter in insert mode. It's basically a personal preference.

Comment: Open `:h insert.txt` and search for `inoremap`, you'll get some examples.

Answer (score 1):

For markdown I have the following mappings in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`:

```
" Break undo sequence at punctuation marks
inoremap <buffer> . .<c-g>u
inoremap <buffer> ! !<c-g>u 
inoremap <buffer> ? ?<c-g>u
inoremap <buffer> , ,<c-g>u
```

I don't think that this makes a difference in my workflow, because I seldom use undo on text that I just typed. It is more likely that I undo a formatting, deletion or copy command.

Anyway, I don't see any negative impact from this.